# How to remove whitespace in pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I have this type of figure containing pseudocode and my result is like shown here:
[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\usepackage{dashbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \fbox{%
        \pseudocode[]{%
            \textsc{\large Left} \<\< \textsc{\large Right} \\[][\hline]
            \<\< \\[-0.5\baselineskip]
            \begin{subprocedure}%
            \dbox{\procedure{\textsc{Short}}{%
                \text{command} \\
                \text{command}
                }}
            \end{subprocedure}\\[-1.5\baselineskip]
            \< \sendmessageright*{(x,y)} \< 
            \<\<\begin{subprocedure}%
            \dbox{\procedure{\textsc{Long }}{%
                \text{command loooooong}\\
                \text{command loooooong}
                }}
            \end{subprocedure}\\[-1.5\baselineskip]
            \< \sendmessageleft*{(a,b)} \<
            \<\< \\[-1.5\baselineskip]
            \begin{subprocedure}%
            \dbox{\procedure{\textsc{Middle }}{%
                \text{command longer}\\
                \text{command longer}
                }}
            \end{subprocedure}
        }
    }
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

How can I achieve that Function "LONG" is aligned at the beginning of the right column?
In other words, I want to remove the white-space between "LONG" and the arrows...

Also, is there the possibility to align "SHORT" to the right, next to the arrow? Such that the white-space would be to its left?

Thank your for helping me out, I can't figure out a valid solution

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: Hi Bernard, the code is now complete :)

Comment: I have somehow solved it by inserting `\hspace*{1cm}` or -1cm after the individual beginnings of the subroutines. It is not a beautiful solution I guess..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first problem, you simply had a wrong count for the columns. 
As to the second problem, as the first column is left aligned, you can add an `\hspace{some length}` in front of the  procedure. The length has to be found by trial and error. Here is a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\usepackage{dashbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \fbox{%
        \pseudocode[]{%
            \textsc{\large Left} \<\< \textsc{\large Right} \\[][\hline]
            \<\< \\[-0.5\baselineskip]
            \hspace{2.75em} \begin{subprocedure}%
            \dbox{\procedure{\textsc{Short}}{%
                \text{command} \\
                \text{command}
                }}
            \end{subprocedure}\\[-1.5\baselineskip]
            \< \sendmessageright*{(x,y)} \<
            %\< \< delet these column changes
            \begin{subprocedure}%
            \dbox{\procedure{\textsc{Long }}{%
                \text{command loooooong}\\
                \text{command loooooong}
                }}
            \end{subprocedure}\\[-1.5\baselineskip]
            \< \sendmessageleft*{(a,b)} \<
            \<\< \\[-1.5\baselineskip]
            \begin{subprocedure}%
            \dbox{\procedure{\textsc{Middle }}{%
                \text{command longer}\\
                \text{command longer}
                }}
            \end{subprocedure}
        }
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Within `\pseudocode` pairs of columns are created; in each pair the first column is left aligned, the second one is right aligned. Thus you need

```
l1 r1 l2 r2 l3
```

Thus “SHORT” and “MIDDLE” should go in column `r1`, ”LONG” in column `l3`.

How to cope with the “Left” label? Put it in column `l1`, with zero width.

The command `\>` is “go to the next column”; `\<` is “go to the column after the next one”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cryptocode}
\usepackage{dashbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\fbox{%
  \pseudocode[]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\textsc{\large Left}} \<\< \textsc{\large Right} \\[][\hline]
    \mbox{} \\[-0.5\baselineskip]
\>  \begin{subprocedure}%
      \dbox{\procedure{\textsc{Short}}{%
        \text{command} \\
        \text{command}
      }}
    \end{subprocedure}\\[-1.5\baselineskip]
    \< \sendmessageright*{(x,y)} \<
    \begin{subprocedure}%
      \dbox{\procedure{\textsc{Long }}{%
        \text{command loooooong}\\
        \text{command loooooong}
      }}
    \end{subprocedure}\\[-1.5\baselineskip]
    \< \sendmessageleft*{(a,b)}
    \\[-1.5\baselineskip]
\>    \begin{subprocedure}%
      \dbox{\procedure{\textsc{Middle }}{%
         \text{command longer}\\
         \text{command longer}
      }}
    \end{subprocedure}
  }
}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]